# Fake localization using bag file in ROS

Tags: localization, ros

I have a bag file that contains couple of topics needed for localization, odometry data, kinect data and `/tf`. What I want is watching robot's movement path in `rviz` after initializing robot position (even I don't know how to initial it). Any help?

All topics:

```
/scan
/tf
/clock
/map
/odom
```

Comment: I don't understand the question – perhaps you could add some context and explain a bit more

Comment: Well, I have recorded data inside a bag file using a wheeled root, right? I've generated map of the environment using that bag file. Now, I want to use these data to see the path of robot inside rviz.

Comment: you might have a better chance of getting an answer for this question if you ask it on the the ROS q/a site: http://answers.ros.org/questions/

Comment: @Robz I did, people there are way too lazy!

Comment: Not 100% sure where's the problem: what do you mean by "after initializing robot position"? Do you mean that you want to run some localisation algorithm on those data? Or did you record the result of the localisation algorithm and simply want to display it?

Comment: @Ugo I want to run a localization algorithm on it

Comment: update question with topics you have in your bagfile

Comment: Why you don't use Matlab? If the visualization is only the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you run rviz, you need to set use_sim_time to true:

```
rosparam set use_sim_time true
```

Now start up rviz, then run rosbag using --clock:

```
rosbag play bagfile_name.bag --clock
```

For setting up rviz with the navigation stack, you will want to follow [this tutiorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Using%20rviz%20with%20the%20Navigation%20Stack).

Answer (score 0):

For localisation you need map of the environment. For the data you have, you should use SLAM algorithm which give path and map of your environment. Try using gmapping in ROS.

Comment: I have map too, sorry I forgot to write its topic name.

Comment: use amcl to localise your robot